# How can I check if Angular is running on production server vs localhost

Tags: angular, typescript

I want some variables that Angular 4 uses to be different depending on whether I am running the app on the production server or on localhost for development. How can I do this? For node.js, I use environment variables but I am not sure if it is possible to use similar environment variables for an Angular web app. What is the best way to approach setting Angular to production without explicitly setting it then deploying?

Comment: It depends how you're building and deploying it. Angular CLI has environment files you can choose from at build time. We've also used server side includes to add things in. If you're not serving static files you may have other options.

Comment: You can also just check the location hostname. If it's your production host, you're in production. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: See https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter for example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you called the `enableProdMode()` method for example in your main.ts file, you can import `isDevMode` from `@angular/core` to check if the angular app is running on prod mod or not.

For example

```
import { Component, isDevMode} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class HomePageComponent {
  constructor() {
    if(isDevMode()){
        console.log("created new HomePageComponent");
    }
  }
}
```

Thats one way to check the app mode.

**But** something that is closer related to environment values are the environment files generated by the angular-cli. With those files you can configurate values that will be setted depending on the mode that you start the live server/build your source. You can find more info in [the following link](http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/)

Comment: Attention! "After [isDevModeis ] called once, the value is locked and won't change any more." https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode You should add this to your answer!

Comment: @jasie feel free to update my answer with your findings as you see fit :)

Answer (score 3):

In the standard project created by Angular-Cli there is a class named 'environment'. You will see you can add different values to the different versions of the class (one is 'production') and the cli will use the correct one when you run

ng build - - prod

Find more info in the docu:
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#enable-production-mode

Use this code to check for production mode:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

console.log(environment.production);
```